# C++ Definite integral for polynom as vector

Tags: c++, symbolic-math, integral, polynomials

I realize this may not be quite the question for SO, and if it is so, I apologize, but I need to do symbolic integration for a polynomial and the way I visualize it doesn't seem like the way to go.

Suppose I have a polynomial, `p[]`, as a vector of order `n`:

`p[0]*x^n + p[1]*x^(n-1) + ... + p[n]*x + p[n+1]`

Suppose I need to integrate this from `1-x` to `1+x`. The way I am trying is by separating each coefficient and using `p[k]*((1+x)^(k+1)-(1-x)^(k+1))/(k+1)`. This would imply convolutions for each `(1-x)` and `(1+x)`, then summing the result, but if this would be feasible for lower orders, for orders more than `10`, the `2x(k+1)` colvolutions for the limits of each of the `10` terms, then `10` multpiplications and additions, index by index, will take a toll. There has to be another, simpler way, is there?

Comment: E.g. the integral of 5*(x^3) is 5*(x^4)/3 + C. I fail to see the problem.

Comment: That is the indefinite integral. For definite, each term is as expressed above: the term times the difference of the limits, power of term plus one. So `5x^3`, from `1-x` to `1+x` means `5*{[(1+x)^4-(1-x)^4]/4}`. Those `1-x` and `1+x` are length 2 vectors that need to be convolved 4 times. At least, based on my math. Do you know of a shorter way for this?

Comment: Well, you can always express a polynomial Ax^3 + Bx^2 + Cx + D as ((Ax + B)*x + C)*x + D. This is called Horner's rule. I'm sorry but I can't make sense of the comment that the indefinite integral is somehow irrelevant or different, and the "convolved" doesn't make sense to me either.

Comment: The Horner method, thanks for the reminder, I forgot about that. For the indefinite integration, `3x^2` becomes `6x^3/3=2x^3`, while `3x^2` from `0` to `1` means `3*{1^3-0^3}/3=1`. If it's from `0` to `x` then it's `3*(x^3-0^3)/3=x^3`.

Comment: I don't get it. You have a nice structure like a polynom. Why don't you simply go with the easily computed antiderivative like Cheers and hth. did, fill in the integration interval and be happy? Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Aziuth What Alf did was *indefinite* integration, what I need is *definite* integration, and not a *numerical* method, either, but *symbolic*. I already gave an example, above, showing the difference between the indefinite integration of `3x^2`, which is `2x^3`, while the definite integration depends on the chosen interval, for example from `0` to `1` it's `1` (numerical method, not what I need), while from `0` to `x` (variable interval, what I need), is `x^3`. You get different results depending on the interval. For `1-x` to `1+x`, integrating the same `3x^2` gives `2x^3+6x`, for example.

Comment: So? Compute the indefinite integral and put in the symbol. As long as your structure can handle not only numbers but also symbols, everything is fine, right? Antiderivative is x^3, plug in your interval gives (1+x)^3 - (1-x)^3 = 2x^3 + 6x, alright. Assuming that what you plug in is alway a polynom, you simply need some class that can handle polynoms, with addition and potence. Not that big of a deal. If you don't have polynoms of order 100, such computations are done in the blink of an eye.

Comment: `1-x` is represented as a length 2 array, `[-1, 1]` (highest power is first). `(1-x)^3` means convolution (polynomial multiplication) of `1-x` with itself, twice. The same for `1+x`. The same for all terms, at their respecive powers. Even if it's unlikely, it can get to `100`, and that's something I must prepare for. As per my question, this is how I do it, currently, but it not only looks like monstruous, it also feels like it. Actually, I just thought that I can save the intermediary results of the convolutions, for the lower terms. This would need a bit more memory, but it will be faster.